# looking on nested list for lot of data python

Tags: python, string, performance, numpy, list-comprehension

I have to find in a nested list which list have a word and return a boolear numpy array.

```
nested_list = [['a','b','c'],['a','b'],['b','c'],['c']]
words=c
result=[1,0,1,1]
```

I'm using this list comprehension to do it and it works

```
np.array([word in x for x in nested_list])
```

But I'm working with a nested list with 700k lists inside so it takes a lot of time. Also, I have to do it a lot of times, lists are static but words can change.

1 loop with list comprehension takes 0.36s, I need a way to do it faster, is there a way to do it?

Comment: If the list is static and you do this a lot, you could index it once and use that index. Since indexing itself is expensive, it wouldn't be worth it for a single pass.

Comment: At a time, as `words`, would you have just one character or there could there be multiple ones?

Comment: Actually, words can have more characters. If words = ['c','b'], then I need 2 boolean array: result=[[1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0]].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could *flatten out* the elements in all *sub-lists* to give us a 1D array. Then, we simply look for any occurrence of `'c'` within the limits of each *sub-list* in the flattened 1D array. Thus, with that philosophy, we could use two approaches, based on how we count the occurrence of any `c`.

**Approach #1 :** One approach with [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
lens = np.array([len(i) for i in nested_list])
arr = np.concatenate(nested_list)
ids = np.repeat(np.arange(lens.size),lens)
out = np.bincount(ids, arr=='c')!=0
```

Since, as stated in the question, `nested_list` won't change across iterations, we can re-use everything and just loop for the final step.

---

**Approach #2 :** Another approach with [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) reusing `arr` and `lens` from previous one  -

```
grp_idx = np.append(0,lens[:-1].cumsum())
out = np.add.reduceat(arr=='c', grp_idx)!=0
```

When looping through a list of `words`, we can keep this approach vectorized for the final step by using `np.add.reduceat` along an axis and using `broadcasting` to give us a `2D` array boolean, like so -

```
np.add.reduceat(arr==np.array(words)[:,None], grp_idx, axis=1)!=0
```

Sample run -

```
In [344]: nested_list
Out[344]: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c']]

In [345]: words
Out[345]: ['c', 'b']

In [346]: lens = np.array([len(i) for i in nested_list])
     ...: arr = np.concatenate(nested_list)
     ...: grp_idx = np.append(0,lens[:-1].cumsum())
     ...: 

In [347]: np.add.reduceat(arr==np.array(words)[:,None], grp_idx, axis=1)!=0
Out[347]: 
array([[ True, False,  True,  True],    # matches for 'c'
       [ True,  True,  True, False]])   # matches for 'b'
```

Comment: It's neccesary to repeat _lens_ and _arr_ on differents loops?

Comment: @jevanio With approach #1 : The last step `np.bincount(ids, arr=='c')!=0` would be the only looping thing. With approach #2 : You won't need to loop as shown in the sample run.

Comment: actually, it makes it more quickly.
Now it took 0,13s.

Comment: @jevanio How much was it with your original approach?

Comment: Originaly it took me 0,3s, the time has decrease a half but it's still much for all the time I have to use u.u

Comment: @jevanio I see, thanks for getting back with those numbers!

Answer (score 1):

A *generator expression* would be preferable when iterating once(in terms of performance).
The solution using `numpy.fromiter` function:

```
nested_list = [['a','b','c'],['a','b'],['b','c'],['c']]
words = 'c'
arr = np.fromiter((words in l for l in nested_list), int)

print(arr)
```

The output:

```
[1 0 1 1]
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html

Comment: It's a little bit faster, just a little u.u

Answer (score 0):

How much time is it taking your to finish your loop?  In my test case it only takes a few hundred milliseconds.

```
import random

# generate the nested lists
a = list('abcdefghijklmnop')
nested_list = [ [random.choice(a) for x in range(random.randint(1,30))]
                for n in range(700000)]

%%timeit -n 10
word = 'c'
b = [word in x for x in nested_list]
# 10 loops, best of 3: 191 ms per loop
```

---

Reducing each internal list to a set gives some time savings...

```
nested_sets = [set(x) for x in nested_list]
%%timeit -n 10
word = 'c'
b = [word in s for s in nested_sets]
# 10 loops, best of 3: 132 ms per loop
```

And once you have turned it into a list of sets, you can build a list of boolean tuples.  No real time savings though.

```
%%timeit -n 10
words = list('abcde')
b = [(word in s for word in words) for s in nested_sets]
# 10 loops, best of 3: 749 ms per loop
```

Comment: right now it took me 0.327 seg per loop, it's too high u.u